# iOS 12.2: device orientation data still blocked even after manual enabling in settings

Tags: javascript, ios, webpack, webpack-dev-server, device-orientation

With iOS 12.2 Apple has blocked access to device orientation data by default. This must be enabled manually now (-__-), as explained [here](https://www.macrumors.com/2019/02/04/ios-12-2-safari-motion-orientation-access-toggle/).

The thing is, even after enabling "Motion & Orientation Access" in settings, I got this warning message on Safari debugger when I try to set a listener on deviceorientation event:

```
function onDeviceOrientationChange (e) {
    console.log(e)
}

window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", onDeviceOrientationChange, false);

// ---> Blocked attempt to add a device motion or orientation listener because the browsing context is not secure.
```

I am developing on [webpack dev server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/). How can I get rid of this block and access device orientation data as before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue recently. Turns out you need HTTPS enabled to access this information. As soon as I enabled HTTPS it worked fine.

Comment: That is so annoying when all I want to do is experiment with it